# swift: "for" loop and "if" statement return four arrays with one element instead of one array with four elements

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops, if-statement

I have an array of NSDate. I am filtering this array with a timeIntervalSinceDate to only keep specific ones. After looping through the array, and submitting an "if" statement to compare the elements in the array with others, I intend to append the desired ones into a new array.

However, after the whole process, it returns an array of one element every time, returning all the right elements, but in separate arrays every time. Instead of having one array of four elements, I end up with four arrays of one

```
     if NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(self.date2) <= 86400 {

                                                for n in self.dateX {

                                                    if n == self.date2 {

                                                     countArray.append(n)

                                                    } } }

} } }}}}}}   })
}}}}
```

Do you have any idea of what might cause this issue ? Why would it return different arrays for each element every time instead of one array with all ?

Comment: Show more code (when you initialize countArray)

Comment: I have updated with the full codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset self.dateX before the begin of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could be seeing what you see is by creating countArray inside the for loop.  I do this in Playground

```
let date2 = NSDate()

let dateX: [NSDate] = [date2, date2, date2]
var countArray: [NSDate] = [] // <<== Not in the for loop

if NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(date2) <= 86400
{
    for n in dateX
    {
        if n == date2
        {
            countArray.append(n)
        }
    }
}
print(countArray)
```

and it prints

```
"[2015-08-04 10:58:06 +0000, 2015-08-04 10:58:06 +0000, 2015-08-04 10:58:06 +0000]"
```

Incidentally, you can create countArray in one line with a filter

```
let countArray2 = dateX.filter{ n in n == date2}
```

Comment: in the playground it works absolutely fine indeed.  I have "for" loops containing all that code.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. however, it still returns me different arrays with singe elements inside.

Comment: If it works fine in the Playground, it'll work fine in your code.  The code you posted in your question will not produce four separate arrays.

Comment: This code is itself within several other "for" loop.   When I create the variable of countArray before one of the loop, it return one single array but with the content not filtered. If I create it inside, it returns the right filtered elements but in different arrays.

Comment: I have updated with the full codes. You see, it is itself included within other "for" loops. I cannot find cleaner manner to do this...